# Add Icon(s) in first line of an event (fullCalendar)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

For specific attributes of an event to be displayed in the 'fullCalendar' matrix I would like to add icons to show them, for 'completed' an (i) button, or an URL symbol in case the event contains an URL link.

I don't want to write any html string to one of the elements (fc-event-time/-title) in the <a> element, but define an additional element like this:

```
<a>
  <span class="fc-event-time">15:15  - 16:15<br></span>
  **<span class="fc-event-icons"> ..some definitions for icons here ..</span>**
  <span class="fc-event-title">Fri Dille</span>
</a>
```

Any help here?
Günter

Answer (score 27):

Well this topic is old, but I couldn't find here how to do it with `<img>` tags so I leave here another way to put images in fullcalendar events:

Add in your `eventObject` a path to the image. If you use javascript it would be something like:

```
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2010-01-01',
        imageurl:'img/edit.png'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2010-01-01'
    }]
```

Then on `eventRender` just put the image:

```
eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
    if (event.imageurl) {
        eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl +"' width='12' height='12'>");
    }
},
```

If you want to use the same image on all items, you just need to put this in your `eventRender`:

```
eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='pathtoimage.png' width='12' height='12'>");
```

Comment: Nice approach. Full Calendar v.2.3.2 doesn't appear to use `fc-event-inner` class any more. Changed the class to `fc-content` instead.

Comment: Sorry for joining so late, but I'm just wondering where to put the eventRender code.

Answer (score 9):

You could piggyback the "eventRender" event like so:

```
$("#YourCalendar").fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.find(".fc-event-time").after($("<span class=\"fc-event-icons\"></span>").html("Whatever you want the content of the span to be"));
    }
});
```

similarly you could append the new element to any other element in the event's DIV container

Comment: AFAIU the 'eventRender' is processed with eg. mouse hover over the event displayed in the calendar.
My request is to "add" things to how the event is displayed, eg. an icon beside the time. So the 'eventRender' is processed after displayed in the calendar, I need to change before it's displayed!?

Comment: No eventRender is processed whenever events are placed on calendar, i.e. on calendar load, event fetch etc.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have to correct this. And it makes things much easier.
Günter

Answer (score 1):

With this you can add text or HTML to the title of your events in Fullcalendar

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {

            var icon  = 'The icon you want, HTML is possile';
                $(element).find('.fc-time').append(icon);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be:

```
  myUtil.goCalendar();       // build calendar with all events 

  // --- post process to add functionality to 'specific' events displayed 
  //     in the calendar matrix, eg. "completed"
  $("div.afc-completed").each(function(){
     $(this).find('span.fc-event-time').addClass("afc-event-completed");
  });
```

With  myUtil.goCalendar(); I building the calendar with all events. That includes to add an event.className ('afc-completed') for all events with that attribute.
After building the calendar I get all those events and add another class to the 'fc-event-time'. That's not what I thought with my first request, but could be a base to add more html code using a CSS statement like this:

```
.afc-event-completed {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

.. or to add icons. Maybe not the best procedure .. but a way to solve the requirement.

Call for experts:
Any other/ better/ shorter/ faster way.
Günter

Comment: Uppps, that's a soltion "second to none" ..
.. with any action (like resize the window, [ < ] or [ > ], etc) all the added 'attributes' are lost. That's due to rendering outside of fullCalendar functions.

Another solution ... like moving the described function to become fullCalendar's.

Any suggestion?

Comment: OK, seems to be solved with:

including 'viewDisplay' & 'windowResize' in the call to

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ..})

I'm very fascinated about the 'full' featured 'calendar' ... GREAT WORK!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by modifying fullcalendar.min.js and removing the `htmlEscape` on the title. Just find the word `HtmlEscape` and remove it. Then in the event calendar you can append icons like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me :

in full calendar 1.5.4

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { 
     //this will add <span> and you can append everthing there
     element.find("div").find("span").before("<span/>").addClass("iconcon");
}
```

and put in CSS

```
.iconcon:before{  //if icon not there then change :before with :after
  font-family: "FontAwesome";  
  content: "\f1fd\00a0";   // \00a0 is blank space
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eventRender: function (calEvent, element) {

    element.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='/imagens/IconExperience/16x16/sms.png' width='16' height='16'>"); 
}
```

-- listener event click

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    if (jsEvent.target.href != undefined) {
        //click on a icon in event
        "http://localhost:64686/imagens/IconExperience/16x16/whatsapp-icon.png"
        etc...
    }
    alert(jsEvent.target.href);
}
```