# How to add an icon in each date of full calendar which popups a form for insert,update and delete event details

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Hello Friends This is my updated code  now i want to add image with unique id which is same as date(mysql- format) and if i will click on image then and then only popup page need to open for new event else part of each date not able to open a popup form but if click on event then need to reopen a form and do not want to append or prepend image before each date but image is need to individual 
Thanks in Advance 
Suggestions is Acceptable

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      if(count==0){
            $(".fc-day-number").before("<img src='/assets/images/add2.png' style='' name='date' id='data-date'>")
            alert(count);
            count++;
            }
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use dayClick event to show popup with form for add event:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#dialog-form').data('date', date).dialog('open');
}
```

end bind double click on event for edit:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.bind('dblclick', function() {
        $('#dialog-form').data('eventid', event.id.toString()).dialog('open');
    });
}
```

For add some image you can use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750521/add-icons-in-first-line-of-an-event-fullcalendar)

Comment: Thanks For Reply But will u tell me how can  i use it

Comment: can i make <div id="dialog-form"> <table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table></div> then is it show me Helloin popup on each date click

Comment: yes, you should define <div> with form inside it, of course you should define jquery dialog on document ready

Comment: thanks dear  it is working as per my requirements but please check my current edit code and tell me how can i pass a date whenever i m click on any date

Comment: you have already date object as first parameter in dayClick function, you can check this by call alert(date.getMonth())

Comment: I know that but i want to use in popup page in which drop down have default date like(click on 23rd feb 2013 then) :::::::: start time: <00:00><am><23><feb><2013> end time: <11:55><pm><23><feb><2013> all of('<>') is drop down box

Comment: why not use [datetimepicker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and [momentjs plugin](http://momentjs.com/) for handle this: 1. define input with datetimepicker 2. format date object by momentjs 3. set date in input

Comment: Because i need to make an appointment schedular web application

Comment: but I think that is better to use one datetimepicker for start date in popup instead of 5 drop down box

Comment: ok thank u so much for a long chat with me & right now i m using for start time & end time this js files http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#AnyTime.picker At this Link u Can Find "Date-Range Selection, Today and Clear Buttons" this is work for me

Comment: this link return 'page not found'

Comment: because it is not more useful so i had removed yesterday