# Displaying image inside a fullcalendar event with eventRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to display an image in the `fc-event-inner` class using `addClass`. I want to do this with `jquery` so I can use different images in different events. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
    title: title,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    allDay: allDay,
    eventRender: function(copiedEventObject,element) {                                          
        element.find('.fc-event-inner').css('background-image',"url(icons/kalender_medicin_100px.png)")
    },
    className: '.fc-event-inner'
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to add an icon or do you want the whole background as image?

Comment: I wan't to add icons with drag and drop.

Comment: You should add it to the `fc-event-content` or `fc-event-title`.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750521/add-icons-in-first-line-of-an-event-fullcalendar

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the `eventRender` in the fullCalendar configuration, not pass it through the `renderEvent` method.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function(copiedEventObject,element) {
        var icon = $(document.createElement('div'));
        icon.css('background-image',"url(icons/kalender_medicin_100px.png)");
        element.find('.fc-event-title').html(icon + copiedEventObject.title);
    }
});
```

If you want to add icons only to the dragged events you can pass an custom property to the event data like so:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
    //...
    isCustom: true,
    //...
}
```

Now you can check if the event has the custom property in the `eventRender` event.

```
eventRender: function(copiedEventObject,element) {
    if(copiedEventObject.isCustom){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Should I put this inside the `renderEvent` method? The code looks right but it does'nt work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. It helped me solve the problem.

But this code only returned an object and did'nt display the image:

```
    var icon = $(document.createElement('div'));
    icon.css('background-image',"url(icons/kalender_medicin_100px.png)");
    element.find('.fc-event-title').html(icon + copiedEventObject.title);
```

So insted of using:

```
   icon.css('background-image',"url(icons/kalender_medicin_100px.png)");
```

I placed the image in the `fc-event-title div`. So the solution is this:

```
    element.find('.fc-event-title').html('<p>Ingen migræne idag</p><img src="icons/kalender_glad_smiley.png"/>');
```

The only problem is that I can't use variables inside the `html` method, but in this context its not a problem. 
Thanks again