# Undefined is not a function on Fullcalendar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Need a help with fullcalendar.js. I found a error "Undefined is not a function" when I see on web inspector. But I think the code is fine.
You can check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3kq85hx0/ for detail.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceDay,resourceWeek,resourceNextWeeks,resourceMonth'
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceWeek',
        firstDay: 1,    
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        minTime: 8,
        snapMinutes:10,
        weekNumbers: false,
        weekNumberTitle: 'Viikko ',
        refetchResources: true,
        maxTime:16,
        selectHelper: true,
        resources: 'json-resources.php',
        events: [       
            {
                title: 'Meeting from this day to this +4',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+4, 11, 00),
                resource: 'resource1'
            },  
            {
                title: 'Meeting last week',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-7, 10, 30),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-7, 12, 15),
                resource: 'resource1'
            },  
            {
                title: 'meeting tomorrow',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 10, 30),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 12, 00),
                resource: 'resource1'
            }   
        ],
        select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view, resource) {
            var title = prompt('event title:');

            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        resource: resource.id
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        resourceRender: function(resource, element, view) {
            // this is triggered when the resource is rendered, just like eventRender
        },
        eventDrop: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            alert('event moved to '+event.start+' to '+event.resource);
        },
        eventResize: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            alert('event was resized, new endtime: '+event.end);
        },
        eventClick: function ( event, jsEvent, view )  {
            alert('event '+event.title+' was left clicked');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `'resourceWeek'` is not a valid value for `defaultView`. If you try to debug the code is show that the expected values are 'month', 'basicWeek', 'basicDay', 'agendaWeek' or 'agendaDay'. Maybe you forgot some plugin?

Comment: If this is a new project, you should probably use the newest Fullcalendar. That is a very old version. The code you have there also contains non-standard stuff so, as Prusse said, you are likely missing some plugin or script.

Comment: @Prusse You are right, I'm missing another plugin. The resource view demo it works now.

Comment: @slicedtoad That fork has fullcalendar with resource view sample, do you have any another solutions?

Comment: @NizamilPutra can you update the fiddle? I need to know exactly what the "resource" plugin adds.

Comment: @slicedtoad Fiddle updated https://jsfiddle.net/3kq85hx0/2/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "undefined is not a function" is coming from within the custom fullcalendar script. Specifically on line **`6373:`**`eventElement.draggable({`.

This is because `draggable` was not defined. `draggable` is part of jqueryui, so I removed your jquery ui script and added one from [google's cdn](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jqueryui).

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kq85hx0/5/) works correctly now.

Also, as discussed in the comments, you are on an old version of fullcalendar. And this particular custom build has a bunch of [issues](https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar/issues).

First, I don't know how long term your plans are but Adam Shaw is currently working on an official [timeline](http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2015/02/timeline-and-other-news.html) update to fullcalendar. You might want to watch for this.

Until then, there is [this fork](https://github.com/ChurchDesk/fullcalendar) that is mostly up to date. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/pull/195). I don't know if it meets your needs but you might want to take a look.

Comment: Great resource @slicedtoad! Thank you.
Anyway how can I add image on every "Room" cell by adding image url in JSON file? Since I'm not good at JS I try to ask you about this.

Comment: @NizamilPutra See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327886/) question. If this answer answered you question, please check the 'accept' button.