# fullcalendar event icon not showing with title

Tags: fullcalendar

I have this code:

```
          {
              id: 'SPAN635585445000000000',
              title: '*Modify Day',
              color: 'purple',
              start: new Date(2015,1,10,0,0),
              className: '.eventItem',
              url: 'mypage.aspx',
              imageurl: 'images/modifyDay.png',
              allDay: true
          },
```

the problem is, the resulting display is just the event title, i want to have the icon (imageurl) to be on the left of the title and show up, right now, the image doesn't show, I have searched google and these discussions to see if I can find a decent way, but I am obviously missing something.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `imageurl` was a built-in option? If you want this kind of functionality, you have to do it manually in the eventRender function: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/ Basically, add a `div` with the image to each event element when they render.

Comment: I kept doing research on this and found some google results:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750521/add-icons-in-first-line-of-an-event-fullcalendar

Comment: They use the `eventRender` function, do you have one? post it if you do.

Comment: Now I am working this from another angle, trying to deal with the eventRender itself, basically like you mentioned, but unfortunately I am now running into a new problem, so going to close this problem but here was the solution:
<code>
eventRender: function(event, element) {
          element.css('font-size','14px');
          if (event.title == '*Modify Day') {
              element.css('background-image', 'url(images/modifyDay.png)'); 
              element.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat'); 
              element.css('text-align: center'); }
          }
  });
</code>

Comment: I can't get the text-align to work, so that is my new problem, so basically slicetoad you have pointed me in the right direction on this, now if I can only get the font to behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eventRender: function(event, element) 
{ 
    element.css('font-size','14px'); 
    if (event.title == '*Modify Day') 
    { 
        element.css('background-image', 'url(images/modifyDay.png)');   
        element.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat'); 
        element.css('text-align: center'); 
    } 
}
```

Thanks to SlicedToad for some pointers on this, although it appears that eventRender is ignoring the text-align property, but this solved the initial problem that I was having where I couldn't get my image to show up.  Since this image is meant to be a type of icon next to the text and is a background image, the text will overlay the image.  The only solution I have found so far is to append periods next to the text until it reaches the point that I am satisfied.  No CSS alignment is working thus far in the eventRender event.title