# FullCalendar - Images as events

Tags: fullcalendar

Looking to use Full Calendar and to include images as events and draggable. In short, would love to see how this example https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.0.1/demos/external-dragging.html would work with small thumbnails instead of the text "My Event 1, My Event 2" etc. And have that image show up on the calendar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add any image url to your eventObject by adding the attribute "imageurl" inside of the events definition (if you just want the image, don't specify a title):

```
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event',
        start  : '2016-10-12',
        end  : '2016-10-14',
        imageurl:'img/edit.png', //you can pass the image url with a variable if you wish different images for each event 
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

After that, you add the following code in the eventRender, which will add the image icon to the event (16 width and height is a good size for a thumbnail):

```
eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
    if (event.imageurl) {
        eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl +"' width='16' height='16'>");
    }
},
```

For further details refer to this question: [Add Icon(s) in first line of an event (fullCalendar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750521/add-icons-in-first-line-of-an-event-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 7):

In version Fullcalendar 5 or newer  `eventRender` is no longer used, instead used `eventContent`
Full code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
              initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
              events: [
                {
                  title: '',
                  start: '2020-09-02',
                  image_url: 'images/demo/event-calendar-1.png',
                },
                {
                  title: '',
                  start: '2020-09-02',
                  image_url: 'images/demo/event-calendar-2.png',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Event',
                  start: '2020-09-17',
                  image_url: 'images/demo/event-calendar-1.png',
                },
                {
                  title: '',
                  start: '2020-09-19',
                  image_url: 'images/demo/event-calendar-3.png',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Hello',
                  start: '2020-09-28'
                },
              ],
              eventContent: function(arg) {
                let arrayOfDomNodes = []
                // title event
                let titleEvent = document.createElement('div')
                if(arg.event._def.title) {
                  titleEvent.innerHTML = arg.event._def.title
                  titleEvent.classList = "fc-event-title fc-sticky"
                }
    
                // image event
                let imgEventWrap = document.createElement('div')
                if(arg.event.extendedProps.image_url) {
                  let imgEvent = '<img src="'+arg.event.extendedProps.image_url+'" >'
                  imgEventWrap.classList = "fc-event-img"
                  imgEventWrap.innerHTML = imgEvent;
                }
    
                arrayOfDomNodes = [ titleEvent,imgEventWrap ]
    
                return { domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes }
              },
            });
            calendar.render();
 
         });
```

Comment: It is better to put the eventContent property on the calendar options and also use renderer2, instead of making direct calls to document. You can then do away with the listener and bind in with fullcalendar's own mechanism.