# Is it possible to add images in fullcalendar instead of events?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to make a calendar with fullcalendar so that the calendar will display images in the place of events (not thumbnails or background images for events) and I was wondering if this is possible to do. Essentially, I am looking to make something like this: http://static.ithome.com.tw/uploads/snapshot/2013010315405850e5360a5f231_thumb.png.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can set the background image of each event, or insert an image tag into each event. Probably the eventRender callback is the best place to do it. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/ Your actual event data could contain a custom property which indicates which image file to use, and use that to manipulate the event's appearance accordingly. You might need to add some custom CSS as well to change how the event appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FullCalendar - Images as events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266483/fullcalendar-images-as-events)