# How to change the full-calendar event's display?

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

I've asked this question before - but i came to realize i didn't described the problem well.

Full-calendar events are being presented as one blue bar that spans over the included dates.

Each event is presented like this :

```
<td class="fc-event-container" colspan="4"> 
    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-
      event fc-start fc-end foo fc-draggable fc-resizable" 
        style="background-
   color:red;border-color:red"><div class="fc-content"> 
   <span class="fc-title">hello</span></div><div class="fc-resizer"></div>
   </a>
</td>
```

Suppose i have an event that span over 4 days - there are not actually 4 tds of content- but one td that span over 4 tds (colspan="4").

I need to add icon to each of the event included days, so it will looks like this : [image]

but i can't because there are no tds to add content....thanks

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/Ld07gav3/)

Comment: Hi!

have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750521/add-icons-in-first-line-of-an-event-fullcalendar ?

Comment: Sure did - unfortunately didn't helped much....

Answer (score 1):

Got it.... [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/odfOSlVZMJppLK68nIsU?p=preview)

Needed to loop over the tds with the dates and then add the icons.

```
            eventAfterRender: function (event, element) {

                    $.each($('td .fc-day-number'), function(){

                        var zone_date =$(this).attr('data-date');

                        var event_start_date = event.start._i;
                        var event_end_date = event.end._i;

                        if( event_start_date == zone_date){


                        }

                        var fDate = new Date(event.start._i);
                        var lDate = new Date(event.end._i);
                        var cDate = new Date(zone_date);

                        if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
                          var foo = $('td .fc-event-container a');
                          $.each(foo,function(){

                            if($(this).hasClass('test') ){
                              $(this).remove();

                            };


                          });



                            var zone_class = event.className.toString();

                            $(this).addClass(zone_class);
                            $(this).css('background-color','red');
                            var current_num = $(this).text();
                            $(this).html(current_num + "<i class='fa fa-
                     circle'></i>");
                        }

                    });

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrq6gf6q/) ? I know it is not the same, but it is kind of soluiton with `eventRender` function. You can update my version, where the icon is multiplied by the event duration.

Comment: Thanks - i've tried it - i need to remove the event itself while keeping the event icon on each td - this is what i've done sor far https://plnkr.co/edit/odfOSlVZMJppLK68nIsU?p=preview

Comment: I see, and I thought that it would not suite you, but the problem is that hard to define the td-s from the `element` parameter of `eventRender` method.